# Search in subfolders

Tags: php, search, subdirectory

I need to extend search to subfolders.

I need a little help to modify and add functions to this script:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['s']) and $_GET['s'] != '') { 
    $dir = 'dir/sub-dir'; 
    $ext = '.htm'; 
    $search = $_GET['s']; 
    $results = glob("$dir/*$search*$ext"); 
    if(count($results) != 1) { 
        foreach($results as $item) { 
            echo "<li><a href='$item'>$item</a></li>\r\n";     
        } 
    } 
    if(count($results) == 1) { 
        $item = $results[0]; 
        echo "<li color='blue'><a href='$item'>$item - only result</a></li>\r\n"; 
    } 
    if(count($results) == 0) { 
       echo "<li>no results to display</li>\r\n";    
    } 
} 
else { 
?> 
<form action=''> 
<input name='s'> 
<input type='submit'> 
</form> 
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in a page on my site and I tried using some of the new recursive directory list functions and they didnt work for me for my application but they may for you. Check this page.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

There are other similar functions built into PHP that are linked to on that page.

For me I used ajax to call a php function I built around scandir() and I passed it the next folder to list. this worked great as it was always a sub folder of the current dir. This way I could make it expand out in a nested list also.

Comment: Thanks John, i will try to setup.